# Dynamically change httpd SSH port on arduino yun using PHP

Tags: php, linux, ssh, arduino

I have successfully changed the SSH port in the /etc/config/uhttpd file using Terminal. But I cannot seem to find a way to do it dynamically from PHP. To explain, I need my server to automatically set the port on the linux system on Yun. So basically I need it to automatically change the port number in the uhttpd file. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by changing the port automatically and changing the port dynamically? Do you want a PHP script to change the configuration file remotely? Something like this: `./myscript.php --host=somehost --port=8788`?

Comment: Yes, I need the php script to change the listening port that the linux chip uses from the default 80 to a different port remotely.

Answer (score 0):

[Setup SSH keys](https://www.howtoforge.com/linux-basics-how-to-install-ssh-keys-on-the-shell) for passwordless access to the remote server.

If the user is not `root`, configure remote `/etc/sudoers` for passwordless command execution via `sudo` command. For example, you can add the remote user to `uhttpd` group(*remotely*):

```
sudo gpasswd -a user uhttpd
```

then list commands allowed to run without password

```
%uhttpd ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

We allowed `ALL` commands for simplicity. You can list specific commands instead. See `man sudoers`.

Write a script similar to the following:

```php
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php
namespace Tools\Uhttpd\ChangePort;

$ssh_user = 'user'; // Change this
$ssh_host = 'remote.host'; // Change this
$remote_config = '/etc/config/uhttpd';

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////

if (false === ($o = getopt('p:', ['port:']))) {
  fprintf(STDERR, "Failed to parse CLI options\n");
  exit(1);
}

// Using PHP7 Null coalescing operator
$port = $o['p'] ?? $o['port'] ?? 0;
$port = intval($port);
if ($port <= 0 || $port > 65535) {
  fprintf(STDERR, "Invalid port\n");
  exit(1);
}

$sudo = $ssh_user == 'root' ? '' : 'sudo';

$sed = <<<EOS
"s/option\s*'listen_http'\s*'[0-9]+'/option 'listen_http' '$port'/"
EOS;

// Replace port in remote config file
execute(sprintf("ssh %s -- $sudo sed -i -r %s %s",
  "{$ssh_user}@{$ssh_host}", $sed,
  escapeshellarg($remote_config)));

// Restart remote daemon
execute("$sudo /etc/init.d/uhttpd restart");

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////

/**
 * @param string $cmd Command
 * @return int Commands exit code
 */
function execute($cmd) {
  echo ">> Running $cmd\n";

  $desc = [
    1 => ['pipe', 'w'],
    2 => ['pipe', 'w'],
  ];

  $proc = proc_open($cmd, $desc, $pipes);
  if (! is_resource($proc)) {
    fprintf(STDERR, "Failed to open process for cmd: $cmd\n");
    exit(1);
  }

  if ($output = stream_get_contents($pipes[1])) {
    echo $output, PHP_EOL;
  }

  if ($error = stream_get_contents($pipes[2])) {
    fprintf(STDERR, "Error: %s\n", $error);
  }

  fclose($pipes[1]);
  fclose($pipes[2]);

  if (0 != proc_close($proc)) {
    fprintf(STDERR, "Command failed(%d): %s\n", $exit_code, $cmd);
    exit(1);
  }
}
```

Save it to `chport.php` and make it executable:

```
chmod +x chport.php
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
./chport.php --port=10000
```

You may want to wrap the commands used in the script in shell scripts, then list them in `/etc/sudoers`.